# Bijection between the set of irrational numbers from 0 to 1 and the set of infinite integers? (Actually, 10-adic integers)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, infinite-groups

It seems to me we can assign to every irrational from 0 to 1 an infinite whole number in the following way:

$$
0.a_1a_2a_3a_4... \rightarrow ...a_4a_3a_2a_1
$$

For example:

$$
0.14159265... \rightarrow ...56295141
$$

As the decimal representation of irrational numbers has infinitely many digits it follows that every whole number defined this way is infinite.

Does it mean that for every infinite whole number there exists a corresponding irrational* number from 0 to 1 and vice versa?

Does this mean that the set of infinite whole numbers is uncountable? Or am I wrong and we are not actually allowed to distinguish infinite numbers?

---

* Except for a countable set of rational numbers, represented by a repeating decimal

---

Since it's been pointed to me that there is no such thing as 'infinite whole numbers', the given above expression can be seen as definition of them. But in that case, they may have no relationship to the usual set of whole numbers, is that right?

---

And these numbers seem to be precisely 10-adic integers, so the question  is answered.

Comment: Why would the reversal need to be irrational? Consider an infinite string of 2's.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but the set of periodic infinite decimals is obviously countable, so my question still stands

Comment: What is an infinite whole number?

Comment: You have exhibited an injective map, so the codomain is uncountable since the domain is.

Comment: I mean precisely an infinitely large number with no fractional part. I think we can define such a set

Comment: There's no concept of "infinite whole number" or "infinitely large number with no fractional part" in common use, so if you want to speak of such a thing you will need to define what you mean by it first. (If you do come up with such a definition, it may well happen that you end up with reinventing the 10-adic integers, which are indeed equinumerous with $(0,1)$).

Comment: @Henning Makholm thanks for the helpful comment, I'll look up 10-adic numbers

Comment: @Hagen despite the nonstandard terminology isn't it clear what the OP means?

Comment: There is no such thing as infinite natural number. On the other hand, the set of all infinite sequences of digits $\{0,\ldots,9\}$ is uncountable.

Comment: @MattSamuel At least it is not clear to me what kinf of number for example $N:=\ldots 11111$ should be. And what is $9\cdot N$? And $9\cdot N+1$?

Comment: @Hagen these would be valid points except that no arithmetic is required here, so there's no problem. It's just an infinite sequence of decimal digits.

Comment: @Hagen if we talk about 10-adic numbers then $...9999 = -1$ and obviously $...9999+1 = 0$ it is valid, since the properties of rational numbers are the same in both 10-adic and R extensions